Do I need to add self leveling compound for sloping slabs before installing LVP?
I have level and flat slabs of concrete on each side of a crack, the crack runs down the center. I intend to run the planks parallel with the crack. Based on my photos, would I be able to get away without doing self leveling? Leveling stick is 48 in and the first photo measures just under 3/8in at 24in from the crack.
https://imgur.com/a/lvp-floor-question-judmTGz
Thank you so much for your time.

I forgot to add details about the vinyl plank.
7.46in wide, 20 mil wear layer, 6mm thick

Is it OK for the vinyl floor to slope? If not you need to level what's under it.

Running parallel to the crack should work, if the slope is constant.  The two edges of the planks at the start of crack might not be as tight fitting as the others, so there might be a noticeable opening(~1/16).  If walking the floor now does not bother you, then it should not after.
